# After using Dynamic Programing in the below question why i m getting time limit exceed?

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

You are given two integer arrays nums and multipliers of size n and m respectively, where n >= m. The arrays are 1-indexed.

You begin with a score of 0. You want to perform exactly m operations. On the ith operation (1-indexed), you will:

Choose one integer x from either the start or the end of the array nums.
Add multipliers[i] * x to your score.
Remove x from the array nums.
Return the maximum score after performing m operations.
Link to question is : https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-score-from-performing-multiplication-operations/

My Sol is :

```
class Solution {
public:
    int calculateResult(vector<int>& nums, vector<int>& multipliers , int index , int left , int right , unordered_map<long long int , int> &umap)
    {
        if(index  >= multipliers.size() )
        {
            return 0;
        }
        
        long long int key = left*100000+right;
        if(umap.find(key)!=umap.end())
        {
            return umap[key];
        }
        int temp2 = multipliers[index]*nums[right] + calculateResult(nums , multipliers , index+1 , left , right-1 , umap);
        int temp1 = multipliers[index]*nums[left] + calculateResult(nums , multipliers , index+1 , left+1 , right , umap);
        umap[key] = max(temp1 , temp2);
        return umap[key];
    }
    int maximumScore(vector<int>& nums, vector<int>& multipliers) {
        unordered_map<long long int , int> umap;
        return calculateResult(nums , multipliers , 0 , 0 , nums.size()-1 , umap);
    }
};
```

Comment: You can avoid many duplicate calculations by using memoization.

Comment: @rebel532 it would be helpful if you could provide the question link, as time limit errors are system dependent and will depend on the site you are solving the problem on.

Comment: @ani1998ket https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-score-from-performing-multiplication-operations/

Comment: @Damien I used memorization to avoid the duplicate calculation. and first check in map . If not found in map then going to call and save and return . for every left and right i call at most one time

Comment: @rebel532 this should be posted in leetcode discuss as there is a whole community that has posted their solutions that you can compare to yours

Comment: @Yash same approach they follow and my sol give TLE that's why problem occurred

Comment: For memoization, using an array should be much more efficient than using a map. Note that `n-right` is less than `m`, to limit the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

For memoization, using a `std::vector` is more efficient than using an `unordered_map`, even if both allows an access in O(1).

Note that `n-right` is less than `m`, which allows to limit the size of the array to `m*m`, i.e `10^6` here.

I have tested the following code versus yours. Very few differences in the code, no difference in the results. However, for maximum values of `m` and `n`, I divided the time by around 10.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <climits>

using std::vector;
using std::unordered_map;
using std::max;

class Solution {
public:
    int calculateResult(const vector<int>& nums, const vector<int>& multipliers, int index, int left, int right, 
      vector<int> &umap){ 
        int m = multipliers.size();
        if (index  >= m) {
            return 0;
        }
        int n = nums.size();
        int key = left*m + (n-1-right);
        if(umap[key] != INT_MAX){
            return umap[key];
        }
        int temp2 = multipliers[index]*nums[right] + calculateResult(nums, multipliers, index+1, left, right-1, umap);
        int temp1 = multipliers[index]*nums[left] + calculateResult(nums, multipliers, index+1, left+1, right, umap);
        umap[key] = max(temp1 , temp2);
        return umap[key];
    }
    int maximumScore(vector<int>& nums, vector<int>& multipliers) {
        int m = multipliers.size();
        vector<int> umap (m*m, INT_MAX);
        return calculateResult(nums , multipliers , 0 , 0 , nums.size()-1 , umap);
    }
};
```